# MySQL selecting rows with max of a given id

Tags: mysql

I know this has to be in here, but I don't know how to ask the question properly:

Here is a simple table:

id / score:
1 / 13
2 / 21
1 / 123
2 / 19

I want to return the max score for each id, in other words:
1 / 123
2 / 21

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY query, with an aggregated [MAX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(score) max_score
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I tried GROUP BY and MAX for a while and made silly mistakes.